# What is essential to make a super capacitor?

Tags: supercapacitor

Assume I have two 5x5 cm aluminum foil sheets and activated carbon powder and a normal A4 paper. If I dissolve the activated carbon powder in water to get something like a paint and painted the aluminum foils with it and let it to dry then placed the paper between the two aluminum foils will I get a super capacitor? is there anything else required? is the electrolyte essential? I saw youtube videos all using graphene electrodes and chemical electrolyte that I can't get. So what's the simplest form of super capacitor that I can make?

Comment: I am not aware of any type of supercapacitor that can be made without specialized equipment.

Comment: Supercapacitors are electrolytic capacitors.   The plates/powder are submerged in electrolyte.   Original supercapacitors used compressed pucks of carbon powder, soaked with sulfuric acid solution, with some sort of separator (paper?) to keep the carbon powder from touching.  The voltage MUST remain well below 0.5VDC, to prevent electrolysis

Comment: This method at best makes a primitive capacitor determined by area/gap and failure determined by surface shorts in <3V/um if not smooth when pressed. If you had C60 carbon >99% , you would get lower leakage but $ , while graphite is conductive and activated carbon TBD

Comment: Also, aluminum is probably a bad choice, since the carbon just touches the oxide layer (insulator,) and aluminum explodes in acid (violent fizzing hydrogen, boiling temperatures.)  Gold works.  What other metal ISN'T destroyed by sulfuric acid?  (What did the youtube guy use?)

Comment: @wbeaty Platinum and rhodium are both immune to sulfuric, I believe. Probably some other noble metals. Tungsten might be okay?

Comment: @wbeaty he used two solid aluminum sheets and sanded the surface. mixed polyurethane with graphene and painted the aluminum sheets and sprinkled some activated carbon on it. he used like a sheet of cloth as separator and dropped some sulfuric acid on the cloth.

Comment: If I did like I wrote in my question what would be the capacity to expect? Will it be better than just using the aluminum with paper without activated carbon?

Comment: @user3926604 "polyurethane with graphene" that's genius.  Coat ANY metal with conductive plastic. But you'd have to mix up a batch that's geniunely a good conductor.  Or try a couple of coats of that carbon-based "wire glue" stuff.

Comment: I'd expect that carbon would give tens/hundreds of times more capacitance.  Can't put aluminum in H2SO4, just try vinegar or salt-water instead.  I think they use sulfuric because it's so low resistance, high amps.  So try a vinegar supercap!

Comment: So if I mixed plastic from plastic bottles with carbon to get conductive plastic. Then coated aluminum foil (cause I want it to bend to wrap a long strip) with the conductive plastic. Then added some activated charcoal powder over that. Then added some vinegar over the separator paper. Will I get something worth trying?

Comment: aluminium is fine in sulphuric acid, they use it for the electrolyte when anodising. lead is fine too,  any metal with an insoluble sulphate will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of articles on the Net describing a DIY approach to making supercaps. None of them come anywhere near the capability of commercial devices. [Here is one of them based on DIY graphene](https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Graphene-Supercapacitor/)

Comment: is it fair to call them supercaps, then? To me, that sounds like an electrolytic cap demonstrator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's the same technology. If it was done properly then it could be used to make a supercap